# Почему исчезают чекбоксы?

Tags: html, css

Есть [сайт](http://door.takercorporation.com/) на главной странице в сайдбаре размещены чекбоксы, при клике они пропадают, я не могу понять почему они пропадают, помогите разобраться, единственное что удалось выяснить, так это то, что блок `.sidebar__check_list_item` смещается, но я не понимаю, почему он смещается. Такая проблема замечена по всему сайту и с радиокнопками такая же проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно причина в этом, там сейчас absolute когда поменял на relative то чекбокс не пропадал

Можете попробовать так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался с багом, помогло :

```
.custom-control-input {
  left: 0;
}
```